# Problem with \mathbb command in times new roman font

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators, amsfonts, mathbb

I have this code written:

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\newfontfamily{\computermodern}{Computer Modern Math}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
```

The real number symbol R appears like that
[image]
but I want to appear like that [image]. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you want so many symbols from computer modern, why not use it for all the math fonts? This mixing of different fonts will make your document look like a ransom letter.

Comment: Never load the `inputenc` package under LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: it would help if you provided an example. Your posted code makes no output. Also how are you using `\computermodern` you have declared an opentype math font as a text font family which seems strange.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz    

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can I pay you in roasted ducks?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz 

Comment: @DavidCarlisle :)

Answer (score 3):

I have deleted `\newfontfamily{\computermodern}{Computer Modern Math}` that crashed my compilation and I have added  `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}` to have the AMS fonts for N,Z,Q,R,C.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}

\begin{document}
$\R$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The AMS blackboard bold fonts are in TeX Gyre Bonum Math, for instance. You should use a math font that matches Times, I suggest STIX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}[range=\mathbb]

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}

\begin{document}

$A\subseteq\R$

$r\in\Q$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might prefer TeX Gyre Termes Math, which is however less complete.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}[range=\mathbb]

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}

\begin{document}

$A\subseteq\R$

$r\in\Q$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't load `inputenc`, `amssymb` or `amsfonts`.